# overflow-x: hidden doesnt work in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have an animated Burger Menu in the mobile view, which slides from right to left into the screen.
With overflow-x: hidden the inactive Menu shouldnt be seen in the page.
In the normal view (smaller browser windows) it works.
But in the mobile view (on my phone or mobile view in browser), after first click on the burger menu, it allows me to scroll right to the space from the "hidden" menu background.

See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlRuy.jpg)

I have a live view of my page, so maybe its better for you to understand instead of posting the whole website code here. I didnt wanted to post only the footer code, as im not sure if maybe its related to something else in the body.

[Live Site](https://radu-pied.vercel.app/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `overflox-x: hidden` to `html`

Comment: i will, i can do it just in 6 minutes :)